# After Assembly.LoadFile setup Callback

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to setup a call back after I load a DLL dynamically using Assembly.LoadFile.   In the below example, "MyCallBackMethod" is a non delegate, so it will not work.   I've created a new DLL, and Reference that DLL in both projects and I can pass that object around, but is that really the correct way to do it or am I overlooking something simple?

```
string fullDLLPath = @"C:\Code\MyTest\MyDLL.dll";
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fullDLLPath);
Type type = assembly.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass");
if (type != null)
{
    //get both the start and stop method 
    MethodInfo myMethod = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
    if (myMethod != null)
    {
        object result = null;
        //create instance
        object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);

        //get all parameters
        ParameterInfo[] paramInfo = myMethod.GetParameters();
        object[] paramToPass = null;
        foreach (ParameterInfo pi in paramInfo)
        {
            paramToPass = new object[] { MyCallBackMethod };
            break;
        }

        result = myMethod.Invoke(classInstance, paramToPass);
        if (result != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I did not understand your exact question, your answer may be laying around here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217198/dynamic-load-dll-with-addeventhandler

Comment: Everybody gets this wrong on the first try, starting with Assembly.LoadFile().  Lots and lots of guidance available when googling "c# plugin architecture", it will show you how to use an interface to do this correctly.  And typically recommend to use MEF.

Comment: I've never used MEF, but when I look it up, there are examples of EXE's calling DLL methods and the DLL has to include the EXE project as a reference.   I need DLL's to call unknown parent EXE methods based on what the EXE passes to it to callback too.   The people writing these DLL's will not have access to the EXE code and the EXE is configured to load the DLL's via it's app.config, which I have already working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just go with a 3rd DLL which is referenced in both projects.   Then I can pass that Class through the object[] with no issues.   The DLL then puts that as a static within it's own Class and can reference that to send messages back to the EXE.

EXE:

```
static public Logger.Textlog Logging { get; } = new Logger.Textlog();
...
foreach (ParameterInfo pi in paramInfo)
{
    paramToPass = new object[] { Logging };
}
```

DLL:

```
static public Logger.Textlog Logging { get; } = new Logger.Textlog();

public bool MyMethod(Logger.Textlog passedTextLog = null)
{
    if (passedTextLog != null) {
        Logging = passedTextLog;
        Logging.WriteLine(LOG_TRANSACTION, "Here");
    }

    ...
}
```